# The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, audio-player

I'm trying to run my project, it was running without any problem, but after I update Android Studio .. I've error and I didn't know which android studio version I was used before update to downgrade to it.

> The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher.
>   The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
>   project ':assets_audio_player' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71

android/app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.10.2, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    // splits {
    //     abi {
    //         enable true
    //         reset()
    //         include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
    //         universalApk false
    //     }
    // }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.mustafakhaled.buzzchat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

}
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar error issue when I added **Flutter Google maps plugin**. I changed the gradle version in android/build.gradle to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1` from `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1` and the Kotlin version to `1.3.21` from `1.2.71`

See code below

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

This actually killed two birds

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are **using version 3.3.1 or the higher** version of the Android Gradle plugin, which enforces to have Kotlin 1.3.0 or above.  so you only have 1 solution - downgrade the **Android Gradle plugin to version 3.2.1**.

Answer (score 1):

Go to External Libraries / Flutter Plugins / assets_audio_player / android / build.gradle and changed ext.kotlin_version to LATEST_VERSION.